# $x^2=2y^2\ln y;\quad y'=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem says that the left function is an implicit solution of that differential equation and I have to prove it.

My try: $$2x=4yy'+\frac{y'}{y}\Rightarrow 2x=y'(4y^2+1/y)\Rightarrow y'=\frac{2xy}{1+4y^2}$$

Comment: To solve what problem, precisely?  I see one equation in $x$ and $y$ and one differential equation.  Are they supposed to be related?  The first is not a solution of the second.  And if you were trying to differentiate the first equation, you did not succeed.

Comment: The problem says that the left function is an implicit solution of that differential equation and I have to prove it.

Comment: @ArturoJoséJiménezRuiz If the first equation is a solution of the second, then I do not understand how to get that negative sign in there. And you did not derive the right hand side correctly (product rule)

Comment: sorry I wrote that bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $x^2=2y^2\ln(y)$ with $y=y(x)$ we obtain by differentiating with respect to $x$:
$$2x=4y\cdot y'\ln(y)+2y^2\frac{1}{y}y'$$ simplifying and solving for $y'$ we obtain $$y'=\frac{x}{2y\ln(y)+y}$$ plugging $$\ln(y)=\frac{x^2}{2y^2}$$ in our formula and we get after simplification:
$$y'=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

It helps to have the correct differential equation.
To make it a bit easier, first divide both sides of the implicit equation by $y^2$ and then take the derivative.  Then you can solve for $y'$.